Merging non-overlapping classified rasters with varying nb of classes
In ArcGIS Pro 3.2, I have several tiles of 1km² as composite rasters (4 bands+NDVI+NDVIre+DSM). I classify each tile independantly with SVM and segmentation, using a training scheme with 8 classes. Classes have a classvalue and a classname attributes, which are the same for all tiles. However, the 8 classes are not present in all tiles, resulting in tiles having a varying number of classes.  The resulting classified rasters are currently saved as 8bit TIF.

My goal is to merge the classified rasters into a single classified raster, while retaining the attributes classname and classvalue, correctly assigned.
I have tried "Mosaic to New Raster" with varying parameters, as well as the full Mosaic process, and "Merge" and "Combine", all without success. The issue seems to lie in the "Value" attribute changing between tiles, and hence being associated with different classvalues as seen in the two attribute tables shown  below. Class 5 is absent from the 1st raster (P71), while present in the second, causing a mismatch between values in "Value" attribut and values in "classvalue"/"classname".


I am unsure how to proceed to merge these rasters while preserving the classification with flexibility.

If you want to ask about doing this in QGIS, Python or R then please do that in separate questions.
